# SQL database structuring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a bit of an issue coming up with a proper solution for a problem I'm having.
Right now, we currently have two tables: Users and Apartments.

Users can search for apartments to rent but they can also "delete" an apartment from their search so that it never comes back again (it should only affect their search).

How (and where) would I be able to store that information?
Thanks!

Comment: You need a third table, where you put all user/apartment wants/not wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user can delete an apartment, then it sounds like you want a `UserDeletedApartments` table.

This would have columns such as:

- `userId`
- `apartmentId`
- date of deletion

You would then incorporate this into the queries that return results to the user.